# How to assign html5 type = "search" to a select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If I look at the code generated for a select_tag, I see type = "text". I tried several ways to overrule this type to the html5 "search" type, using "as: :search", and using html options, but to no avail. Is there a way to overrule the default type = "text"?

Answer (score 0):

Include as normal as type search I think no need of as::search there. The syntax is as follows:

```
<input type="search" name="googlesearch">
```

Otherwise you can use search tag as follows: [look at here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-search_field_tag)

search_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})

Comment: I really need the select options, so using input or search_field_tag is no option. In fact I want to add the "visual appeal" of the html5 search field to an autocomplete select tag...